# Android studio 2.3 refreshing continuously

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I've recently updated android studio to 2.3...After update it is continuously refreshing the project.So I clicked on invalidate cache and restart..After that it is showing this error

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lgm0.jpg)

This is my build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
#Mon Mar 13 16:42:48 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

This is my gradle location

```
C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-3.2
```

Everything seems to be good to me.I dont know what should I change...Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who face similar problem here is the solution.Download gradle files manually from internet which is of around 80 mb and replace these new files with those of old ones in android stuido.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the blue link - Upgrade Gradle Wrapper - that should fix it

Comment: That link was disabled. Its not doing anything on clicking that link